# right way compare types in generic

Tags: c#, generics

In generic method I have to do different actions for each Type. I do it so:

```
public static T Foo<T>(string parameter)
    {
            switch (typeof(T).Name)
            {
                case "Int32":
                    ...
                    break;

                case "String":
                    ...
                    break;

                case "Guid":
                    ...
                    break;

                case "Decimal":
                    ...
                    break;
            }
    }
```

Is there better way to know Type T? **if (T is int)** does not work.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use `if` in combination with `typeof(<the type to test for>)`:

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))
{
    // Foo has been called with int as parameter: Foo<int>(...)
}
else if(typeof(T) == typeof(string))
{
    // Foo has been called with string as parameter: Foo<string>(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T))) {
    case TypeCode.Int32: 
        break;
    case TypeCode.String:
        break;
}
```

This only works for the basic types defined in the [`TypeCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode.aspx) enumeration though (which don't include `Guid`). For other cases, `if (typeof(T) == typeof(whatever)`) is another good way to check types.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Dictionary<Type, Action<object>`:

```
class TypeDispatcher
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> _TypeDispatchers;

    public TypeDispatcher()
    {
        _TypeDispatchers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();
        // Add a method as lambda.
        _TypeDispatchers.Add(typeof(String), obj => Console.WriteLine((String)obj));
        // Add a method within the class.
        _TypeDispatchers.Add(typeof(int), MyInt32Action);
    }

    private void MyInt32Action(object value)
    {
        // We can safely cast it, cause the dictionary
        // ensures that we only get integers.
        var integer = (int)value;
        Console.WriteLine("Multiply by two: " + (integer * 2));
    }

    public void BringTheAction(object value)
    {
        Action<object> action;
        var valueType = value.GetType();

        // Check if we have something for this type to do.
        if (!_TypeDispatchers.TryGetValue(valueType, out action))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown type: " + valueType.FullName);
        }
        else
        {
            action(value);
        }
    }
```

This can then by called by:

```
var typeDispatcher = new TypeDispatcher();

typeDispatcher.BringTheAction("Hello World");
typeDispatcher.BringTheAction(42);
typeDispatcher.BringTheAction(DateTime.Now);
```